# How to "properly" handle incorrect values in a random walk?

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms

I'm performing a simple one dimensional walk to create sample interest rates. Whilst I know there are lots of options for encouraging values to oscillate around a mean etc. I'm yet to find a simple "proper" way to handle truly random processes going out of bounds. Whilst you could simply turn it in the other direction, is there some sort of commonly accepted way of making asymptotically less and less likely to get closer to the boundary the closer you get to it?

Comment: What do you mean by a "truly random process"? How is it "untrue" to just declare the probability of going from zero to any smaller value to be zero? And what do you mean by "asymptotically less likely"? A function that maps some finite input to zero isn't reaching an asymptote there: for an asymptote, you need something to be going to infinity. Finally, I'm not sure this is really a computer science question? While plenty of computer scientists could probably answer it, there doesn't seem to be any computational content in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make it clear enough. Maybe it's not appropriate for this site. So I am performing a random walk (with a computer) to mimic a process. This process has boundaries i.e. the walk can't go up to infinity or down past zero. I was wondering if there was an accepted solution in computer science to making it practically impossible to extend boundaries in a smooth/clean way that involves no jumps or turn-arounds. I'm looking for any commonly accepted solutions in computer science to adapting a random walk (a computer science thing) to have bounds.

Comment: IIRC, *simulated annealing* is a term for changing the probabilities as time goes on. But then, you need changes w.r.t. location, right? (Do you know [stats.SE]? They may have more experts from this domain. Please flag your question if you want it migrated there.)

Answer (score 1):

A random walk $(X_i)$ can't become negative if there are no positive-probability transitions to negative values. One condition that causes it to stay finite with probability $1$ is that, for all large enough $n$, $\mathbb{E}(X_{i+1}|X_i=n)<n$.